# On a Starfleet vessel, what happens if there are no officers available to take the command?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-rank

Thinking about the TNG episode "Disaster", Lt. Munroe was killed during the impact. The episode plays out with Deanna taking command, but what would have happened if the only remaining crew on the bridge were non-commissioned officers? For instance, if O'Brien and other chiefs were the only survivors of the bridge? Is there a canon reference for chain of command in such a situation?

Comment: The senior non-commissioned officer gets the nod...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the episode [*DS9: Valiant*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Valiant_(episode)), we encounter a ship that was on a training cruise. The senior staff all died and the remaining officer ***gave command to the highest ranked cadet***.

> **WATTERS:** (tolerant) *"Sir" is correct, ensign. I was given a battlefield commission and command of this vessel by the late Captain Ramirez. Using that authority, I've also commissioned and promoted other members of Red Squad as needed.*

Note that in this instance, instead of doing what's appropriate (e.g. navigating the ship to the nearest real officer to allow them to take over) Watters has been playing at being captain because he doesn't want to stop.

---

As to what would happen if this was a *normal* crew, the [NCO with the highest rank](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Non-commissioned_officer) would almost certainly have taken charge. Everyone on the ship that isn't a civilian holds a rank.

In the event that a senior officer is missing, everyone defers to the next most senior all the way down to [Crewman 3rd class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Crewman), which is basically the guy who makes sure the vending machines don't run out of fun-size Munchie Bars.

Comment: Although I agree that this specific example is a good one for what *could* happen, the question was about what if all officers had been taken out before such battlefield commisions could occur.

Comment: I recall an incident, possibly from a Henry Wouk novel, where two juniors argue over who would take charge of a vessel after the entire command staff are killed. In the end one 'pulls rank' because his naval service number was higher than the other's, despite them having the same rank, because he'd enlisted a few days earlier.

Comment: You'd think the lower number was older, unless they give out ID numbers in descending order for some reason.

Comment: @Cadence - I forget how it worked

Comment: @Valorum That is the way it works... Someone who is 3 years at a rank is Senior to someone with 2 years and 364 days. Unless specifically directed by an officer to appoint the junior to the senior position. (i.e. Your in charge of this away team.) The one with more time in rank is senior. In the US Navy there is a tradition, The Ensign with the most time in rank (or grade) on a ship is called the "Bull" Ensign. and his Ensign collar bar had the word "Bull" engraved on it.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky even in peace time and in the absence of commissioned officers, there are non-commissioned officers on the ship. [Memory Alpha documents the various ranks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_ranks), you're looking for "Enlisted Ranks". Field promotions, such as Janeway gave the Maquis crew, would be "Provisional Ranks". In the absence of commissioned officers, it would fall to non commissioned officers to take charge, as explained above.

Comment: @NJohnny that'd probably make Harry Kim the highest ranked ensign in history :p

Comment: "the guy who makes sure the vending machines don't run out of fun-size Munchie Bars"  Was that on purpose?  :-D

Comment: @A.B. - That was a Red Dwarf reference (RD: Justice)

Comment: From what I learned at real life military service, *anyone* can claim the command when the others agree. The average guy doesn’t want to take the burden of responsibility, that’s why it works. No-one would challenge the new command, just because being in service an hour longer than the other. They’re just happy that someone is willing to do it.

Comment: Real-world retired senior NCO here. Precedence goes as follows: (1) Highest-ranked member is senior. (2) If two or more members share this distinction, the one with the earliest date-of-rank is senior. (3) If there is still a tie, the one with the earliest time-in-service date is senior. (4) If there is still a tie, the one born first is senior.

Comment: Also, a man put in command of a vessel is senior to everyone else on the vessel, when it comes to the operation of that vessel, and a guard at his post outranks *everybody*.

Comment: @EvilSnack Insert anecdotes about five-star generals being turned away at the gates because they forgot their ID, and variously raging at, or commending, the guard for doing his duty.

Comment: @Valorum Haha I wondered if it was  :-D

Comment: If you drill down you will find that in cases where a lower-ranking person can give orders to a higher-ranking person, it is because the junior person has the backing of someone who outranks everyone else involved.